# Issue with Asterisk on Google compute engine (GCE)

Tags: asterisk

I installed and configured Asterisk in Google compute engine (GCE). I am facing the below issues:

1) Unable to login to Asterisk CLI by using asterisk -rvvvvv command (But, I am able to login using asterisk -vvvvvc 2) I am able to make calls between the extensions. But, unable to make/receive PSTN calls. When I am trying to call to PSTN number through my provider, traffic is not going to out side world from my instance.

I opened the UDP ports in the GCE GUI Firewall.

Is there any modifications that I need to do in Google Compute Engine (GCE) environment?

Please note that I deployed my same server in different other environments like Amazon ec2 and working successfully. But, the same configured server is not working on GCE.

Thanks in advance.

Chandra.